# Is martingale solution equivalent to weak solution for SDE driven by stable process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Consider the following SDE
$$
d X_t=b(X_t)\,d t+d L_t,
$$
where $L_t$ is the symmetric $\alpha$-stable process. The corresponding generator is given by
$$
L=\Delta^{\alpha/2}+b\cdot\nabla.
$$
Is the solution for the martingale problem of $L$ equivalent to the weak solution of the above SDE? (For Brownian motion case, it is well known. But for jump Levy noise, I couldn't find any reference books.)

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, it is... take a look at the following paper: Kurtz, T. G.: Equivalence of stochastic equations and martingale problems. In: Stochastic Analysis 2010. Springer, 2011.

Comment: Thanks for the help!